# How to add a field to another module in Odoo 14

Tags: python, xml, odoo

Good day!
How can I add a field to the payment's module here is my code, but I get an error:

```
odoo.exceptions.ValidationError: Error while validating view:

Field "term_number" does not exist in model "account.payment"

View name: account.payment
Error context:
 view: ir.ui.view(1133,)
 xmlid: view_account_payment_form
 view.model: account.payment
 view.parent: ir.ui.view(562,)
 file: c:\program files\odoo 14\server\odoo\addons\doc_dte_school\views\payment.xml
```

Here is my XML code

```
<record id="view_account_payment_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">account.payment</field>
    <field name="model">account.payment</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.view_account_payment_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="amount" position="after">
            <field name="term_number"/>
        </field>
    </field>
</record>
```

Here is My Python code

```
from odoo import api,fields,models,_

    class AccountPayment(models.Model):
        _inherit = 'account.payment'
        _inherit = 'dte_school'
        
        term_number = fields.Many2one('dte_school')
```

Comment: You redefined the ``inherit`` attribute value, so you are extending the ``dte_school`` model

Comment: @Kenly am new at odoo i don't get you

Comment: You have set the inherit attribute twice, so its value will be the last one. If you need to extend `account.payment` model and add the `term_number` field, you have just to use `_inherit = 'account.payment'` and remove `_inherit = 'dte_school'`

Comment: Did you get rid of the error

Comment: Thank you, i have, did as you have surjected and it is working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inherit like this.

```
from odoo import api,fields,models,_

class AccountPayment(models.Model):
    _inherit = ['account.payment', 'dte_school']
        
    term_number = fields.Many2one('dte_school')
```

Comment: Am still getting the same error

Comment: I have also tryied this but am getting the same error
   <xpath expr="//field[@name='amount']" position="after">
     <field name="loan_number"/>
   </xpath>

Comment: did you add the py file containing this class AccountPayment(models.Model) to the "__init__.py" file?

Comment: Yes i did, add it